# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' when I 'return' in the request

Tags: angular, typescript

task.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebRequestService } from './web-request.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TaskService {
  constructor(private webReqService: WebRequestService) {}

  createList(title: string) {
    return this.webReqService.post('lists', { title });
  }

  getLists() {
    return this.webReqService.get('lists');
  }
}
```

task-view.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss'],
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {
  lists: any[];

  constructor(
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      console.log();
    });

    this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any[]) => {
      this.lists = lists;
    });
  }
}
```

I get the error on the task.service.ts line(23):
this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any[]) => {

error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

I know there are a lot of questions on the Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'
but they all seem to be resolved by putting in 'return' to the request;

However I did not forget 'return' in my getLists() method. I am confused why it is accepted as a void method when there is a return, and how to go about fixing this error.

Comment: Does `WebRequestService.get` also have a return in it?

Comment: code of webrequestservice?

Comment: Oh wow... ;( I did not overlook that. Thank you;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to add return to WebRequestService.get

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebRequestService {
  readonly ROOT_URL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
  }

  get(uri: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }
```